# Dynamic annotation in SVG

Tags: html, dynamic, svg

We have a need to dynamically annotate certain points in an SVG rendering with some labels (divs).

Is there any algorithm that will allow us to dynamically determine the position for these label annotations that will fully avoid or minimize overlap?

The annotation would be a line from the points to a label (a div with some text)

Comment: Need more info:  is this an SVG file that you are embedding into a page or are you generating the SVG dynamically?  If so what library are you using?  Do you have something up where we could see it?

Comment: We are just using jQuery to create the SVG. We have already drawn things in the SVG. Now, we want to annotate certain points (with a line from the point to a label), but the position of these labels will have to be dynamically calculated to avoid overlap. 

Sorry, I don't have anythign to share. Hope the requirement is clear.

Answer (score -1):

Its something you need to create points dynamically.

Please refer to [this link](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/simplerandomwalk.svg) which shows dynamic random walk within points along with allocation.

Also you may go through [the link](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/SVGAnimations.htm) for other details regarding SVG Animations.